# JavaScript Debugger Keyword and Scope Issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I noticed some strange behavior upon using the debugger keyword on Chrome 35 (See snippet below or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPC3C/11/)):

```
function Person (settings) {
    // ....
    settings.init();
}


var anchors = document.querySelector('a');
var bob = new Person({
    init: function () {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

I noticed that inspecting the value of 'anchors' in the console on the debugger breakpoint was returning a ReferenceError stating that anchors is not defined.  However, when I inspected anchors on the debugger breakpoint of this snippet ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPC3C/12/)):

```
function Person (settings) {
    // ....
    settings.init();
}


var anchors = document.querySelector('a');
var bob = new Person({
    init: function () {
        debugger;
        console.dir(anchors);
    }
});
```

anchors returned `null`, which is a sane value for `document.querySelector` to return.  anchors is most certainly existent in the anonymous function's scope.  Is this a bug in Chrome or expected behavior?

Comment: I believe, if i am not wrong, its due to garbage collection. Since `anchors` is not referenced anywhere else it does not keep it around. Note if you change the function call after debugger to anything besides `eval` or a any statement that does not reference `anchors` it will not show `anchors` as being defined. But once you put an `eval` call in or a call referencing `anchors`, `anchors` is then showed as defined as null

Comment: @PatrickEvans but if the anonymous function contained no reference to anchors and I put an actual breakpoint on a line in the function then anchors would be accessible to me when I log it to console or watch it.  Does the debugger keyword not function like a regular breakpoint?

Comment: Well testing more, my garbage collection theory is wrong. But my watch list does not show `anchors` as being defined, when stopped in the `init` function or within a closure that does not reference it. So this might be expected behavior since it is not referenced the debugger does not bother watching it or listing it in the scope variables. But that is also just a theory i havent found anything yet that would explain this behavior.